# MATLAB How to delete a specific page from a .pdf File?

Tags: matlab, pdf

I recently learned how to download `.pdf` files using **`urlwrite`**, but I was wondering if there is any way to specify which pages of the `.pdf` to save.

The files are always either 1 or 2 pages long, and I only want to keep the first page of the `.pdf`. Is there any way to directly download just the first page, and if not, is there a way to download the entire `.pdf` and then get rid of the 2nd page?

I know that it is possible to manually get rid of the second page in Preview or Adobe Acrobat and other applications, but it'd make things a lot easy if I could automate the process in MATLAB.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Simply put you can't.  You need to fully reconstruct the PDF before you choose to delete a page.  That's the nature of the PDF standard and how it compresses data.  You're SOL.... sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the input, I really appreciate it. Not what I was hoping to hear, but it's definitely not the end of the world.

Comment: `is there a way to download the entire .pdf and then get rid of the 2nd page?` Completely out of matlab but for tasks like this, e.g. splitting /merging pdfs, I recommend and use [SmallPDF](http://smallpdf.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find an appropriate command line tool (example uses [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/)), and then you can make a call to it from MATLAB.  Use `sprintf` to assemble the appropriate command and then pass it to `system`.  This puts the output in a temporary file then uses `movefile` to change the filename back:

```
temp = 'sometempfile.pdf';
urlwrite(someurl, filename);
system(sprintf('pdftk %s cat 1 output %s dont_ask',filename,temp));
movefile(temp, filename);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I downloaded pdftk and used `urlwrite` to download a file, but when I run `system(sprintf('pdftk %s cat 1 output %s dont_ask','test.pdf','test.pdf'));` in MATLAB, I get `/bin/bash: pdftk: command not found`. Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @milesda, looks like pdftk is not properly installed. Best way to do it is to use your distribution's package manager.

Comment: @A.Donda I am able to successfully use pdftk in Terminal, so I know that it works independently. That being said, is there something else I must do so that MATLAB can access pdftk? I'm using Mac OS X 10.9

Comment: Alright, it looks like I got it working in MATLAB by adding `/usr/local/bin/pdftk` at the beginning of the pdftk code! However, it won't let me overwrite the file and tells me `The given output filename: /Users/Desktop/test.pdf matches an input filename.  Exiting.` Is there a way in pdftk to have the input and output be the same file?

Comment: If it won't do it in one step, output to a temp filename and then `mv` the temp file back over the original.